# Camera attached axis

Tags: reactjs, babylonjs

In my react app I have a babylonjs scene component created according to babylonjs's [example code](https://doc.babylonjs.com/resources/babylonjs_and_reactjs) and also am using the axis code from [this example](https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#2EYZPE) where `onSceneMounted` in React example is basically the `createScene` from axis example. What I would like to do is to instead of placing the axis to the scene origin in scene space, I would like to show them in upper right corner, similar to how Unity editor does it.

[image]

The axes are always pinned to the upper right corner and are rotated according to the camera rotation.

Comment: How do you place your axis? Using gizmos?

Comment: Just like in the example linked.